# except jquery lazy load, how to add a `loading.gif` when php images are loading?

Tags: php, jquery

I do not want to use jquery lazyload. because I want loading done all the pictures then show at the same time, not loading one by one.

I know some thing like this, but how to make a judge when all the images are loaded, then remove the `loading.gif`? thanks.

```
$("div#content").prepend("<img src='../loading.gif' class='ldrgif' / >");//add a image
...//loading images in div#content
$(this).find("img.ldrgif").remove(); //remove it, how to make a judge all the images are loaded?
```

Comment: because `$(document).ready(function () {alert("Images Loaded");});` runs when the dom is finished, wouldn't that mean the images are loaded?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a neat example: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y3dW/**

Comment: it always loading, but not show the images. i test in opera 10, and firefox 4.